# Which class should I change to make my menu margin different than text from menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

my menu and menu items content look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbIVJ.jpg

When you click on menu item, the green panel slides up and show text; menu items and content are connected in JavaScript.

I want to change some class to make green panel show lower than menu items.

```css
.menu ul {
  float: right;
}

.menu ul li {
  background: #161616;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu ul li:not(.active):before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu ul li:not(.active):focus:before,
.menu ul li:not(.active):hover:before {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #529ecc, #9CF5A6);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu .panel {
  display: none;
  background: #33b1a2;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}

.menu .panel.active {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

.active {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #529ecc, #9CF5A6);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="main">
    <li rel="onas" class="active">
      O NAS
    </li>
    <li rel="zajmujemysie">
      ZAJMUJEMY SIĘ
    </li>
    <li rel="oferta">
      OFERTA
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="onas" class="panel active">
    O NAS - ...
  </div>
  <div id="zajmujemysie" class="panel">
    ZAJMUJEMY SIĘ - ...
  </div>
  <div id="oferta" class="panel">
    OFERTA - ...
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't matter which class I change, green panel and menu items shows always in the same line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include the relevant JS to we have a working example, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: both` to the div with the id of 'onas':

```
#onas {
  clear: both;
}
```

This clears the floats and ensures that the onas div will be placed below the menu.